# Can I change the validation rules required for different actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have a model that looks like this -

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name,:presence =>true
end
```

Can I set it up so that the car's name is not required when preforming a create action but it is required when doing an 'edit' action?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yup, that's possible:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true, on: :update
end
```

Might have a look at the [Active Record Validations and Callbacks Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#on).

Comment: Just to complete the answer, you can do more than :update or :create (which are default contexts for save and valid? methods). You can use any symbol you want and then pass that same symbol to save or valid? methods to trigger specific validations: if you have some validation with something like "on: :some_context" you can call "obj.save(context: :some_context)" or "obj.valid?(:some_context)".